# Twain DataSourceManager

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009, twain

I added a twainScanner .dll reference to ax2009. And I have a problem with initiation. How to initiate DataSourceManager object with ax form? I tried a lot of tips, but everytime i got error The '1' argument is incompatible with the required type.

```
void openScannerForm()
{
    Args                                  args;
    FormRun                               formRun;
    TwainScanning.AppInfo                 app;
    TwainScanning.DataSourceManager       twainDSM;
    ;

    app = new TwainScanning.AppInfo();
    twainDSM = new TwainScanning.DataSourceManager(*HERE I HAVE A PROBLEM* , app); //this object require Form parameter, how to get it ?
}
```

[image: PictureHere]

Comment: I would not expect an extern DLL to accept AX forms. What does the documentation regarding the instantiation of the objects? What is AppInfo?

Comment: I know nothing about Twain, but it sounds like the DLL wants to "manage" the form's datasource and it appears you need to pass an **AX** `Form` object to it. You have `FormRun` defined, but not instantiated. I would guess you need to run this code **on** an actual form and pass an `element` object or you would do `FormRun.Form()`.